# Script works when using form's NAME, but not ID or CLASS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've set up the following fiddle where my script works to populate two text fields based on their selection in a drop down. A you can see, I set up an array of values for the text boxes and then connect the right values with a script based on the value for the drop down. Unfortunately, I specified a name for the form - bubblegum - which I can't do in the real life version as the form is generated by Gravity Forms. I've tried several options to reference the form by CLASS ("form.cart") or ID, but can't seem to get it to work. I believe it's just a simple case of incorrect syntax, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dh4Q5/23/

HTML:

```
<form id="gform_1" class="cart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="bubblegum" action="">
<div class="gform_variation_wrapper gform_wrapper">
<input id="product_id" type="hidden" value="36" name="product_id">
<input id="_wpnonce" type="hidden" value="5d7e85ce15" name="_wpnonce">
<input type="hidden" value="/product/prepare-for-your-closing-copy/" name="_wp_http_referer">
<div id="gform_wrapper_1" class="gf_browser_gecko gform_wrapper">
<div class="gform_body">
<ul id="gform_fields_1" class="gform_fields top_label description_below">
<li id="field_1_13" class="gfield gfield_price gfield_price_1_13 gfield_product_1_13 gfield_contains_required">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_13">
Quantity
<span class="gfield_required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<select id="input_1_13" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="1" name="input_13">
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_14" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_14">Total</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<span class="ginput_total ginput_total_1">$269.00</span>
<input id="input_1_14" class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" name="input_14" value="269">
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_1" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_1">Location</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<select id="input_1_1" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="2" name="input_1">
<option value="DFW Locations...">DFW Locations...</option>
<option value="Addison">Addison</option>
<option value="Arlington">Arlington</option>
<option value="Colleyville">Colleyville</option>
<option value="Fire Wheel">Fire Wheel</option>
<option value="Flower Mound">Flower Mound</option>
<option value="Fort Worth">Fort Worth</option>
<option value="Legacy">Legacy</option>
<option value="Mansfield">Mansfield</option>
<option value="McDermott">McDermott</option>
<option value="Preston Corners">Preston Corners</option>
</select>
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_19" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_19">Address</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<input id="input_1_19" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="3" value="" name="input_19">
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_21" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_21">City, State, ZIP</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<input id="input_1_21" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="4" value="" name="input_21">
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_11" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_11">Reference</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<input id="input_1_11" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" name="input_11">
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_12" class="gfield">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_12">Notes</label>
<div class="ginput_container">
<textarea id="input_1_12" class="textarea medium" cols="50" rows="10" tabindex="6" name="input_12"></textarea>
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_15" class="gfield gform_hidden">
<input id="input_1_15" class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="Vendor X" name="input_15">
</li>
<li id="field_1_22" class="gfield gfield_html gfield_html_formatted gfield_no_follows_desc">
<a id="mylink" target="_blank" href="#">Send to PDF</a>
<span>the link contains: </span>
<span id="showmehref"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="gform_footer top_label">
<input class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="1" name="is_submit_1">
<input class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="1" name="gform_old_submit">
<input class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="" name="gform_unique_id">
<input class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="WyJhOjE6e2k6MTM7YToyOntpOjA7czozMjpcIjYzNDM5OTkzYmRhMDU2NGM5NWUwNGU4ZDgyNTM4NWFiXCI7aToxO3M6MzI6XCI1MTk1MjNiNmI1ZDM0NDk2NmJhZGY3M2I4YzIxYWEyYlwiO319IiwiMTYzYjgzMmJjODZhMWU2NzJkYTQ5YTQ3OWE2OWJjMzciXQ==" name="state_1">
<input id="gform_target_page_number_1" class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="0" name="gform_target_page_number_1">
<input id="gform_source_page_number_1" class="gform_hidden" type="hidden" value="1" name="gform_source_page_number_1">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="gform_field_values">
</div>
</div>


<input id="gform_form_id" type="hidden" value="1" name="gform_form_id">
<input id="woocommerce_get_action" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="woocommerce_product_base_price" type="hidden" value="0">


</div>
<input type="hidden" value="36" name="add-to-cart">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
<input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
<input class="input-text qty text" type="number" size="4" title="Qty" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" step="1">
<input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="36" name="add-to-cart">
<button id="gform_submit_button_1" class="addToCart single_add_to_cart_button button alt gform_button" type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Script:

// JavaScript Document

```
// Pre populated array of data
var myData1 = new Array();
myData1['Addison'] = '14295 Midway Road, Suite 100';
myData1['Arlington'] = '1241 W. Green Oaks Blvd., Suite 101';
myData1['Colleyville'] = '1210 Hall Johnson Road, Suite 150';
myData1['Fire Wheel'] = '650 Beebalm Lane, Suite 260';
myData1['Flower Mound'] = '3020 Corporate Court, Suite 400';
myData1['Fort Worth'] = '4421 Oak Park Lane, Suite 102';
myData1['Legacy'] = '7500 Dallas Pkwy., Suite 175';
myData1['Mansfield'] = '1405 N. Highway 287, Suite 101';
myData1['McDermott'] = '3915 McDermott Road, Suite 2000';
myData1['Preston Center'] = '8201 Preston Road, Suite 450';
var myData2 = new Array();
myData2['Arlington'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Addison'] = 'Arlington, TX 76013';
myData2['Colleyville'] = 'Colleyville, TX 76034';
myData2['Fire Wheel'] = 'Garland, TX 75040';
myData2['Flower Mound'] = 'Flower Mound, TX 75028';
myData2['Fort Worth'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Legacy'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Mansfield'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['McDermott'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Preston Center'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';



    document.bubblegum.input_1.onchange = updateText;

    function updateText() {
      var obj_sel = document.bubblegum.input_1;
      document.bubblegum.input_19.value = myData1[obj_sel.value];
         var obj_sel = document.bubblegum.input_1;
      document.bubblegum.input_21.value = myData2[obj_sel.value];

}
```

So I guess I just need a different way to reference the form than using the NAME, since I can't set the name in the actual application.

Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById('gform_1').input_1` ??? BTW, why it is tagged with jQuery? If it is what you are looking for, then seriously please read some basic tutos...

Comment: change JavaScript to `document.getElementById('gform_1').onchange = updateText;

        function updateText() {
          var obj_sel = document.getElementById('gform_1').input_1;
          document.getElementById('gform_1').input_19.value = myData1[obj_sel.value];
             var obj_sel = document.getElementById('gform_1').input_1;
          document.getElementById('gform_1').input_21.value = myData2[obj_sel.value];

    }`

Comment: Yes, that works... that is awesome! Thanks to both of you! Is it possible to use class as well?

Comment: Yes: `var theForm = document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0];`.  I'd also suggest passing `theForm` into your function.  Less DOM references, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use document.getElementById(), document.getElementsByClassName() and take the first item in the list.  Also, keep your script clean with as few direct DOM references as possible.  You should set a variable, pass it into your function and use the variable.  For example:

```
function updateText(form) {
     var obj_sel = form.input_1;
     ...
}
updateText(document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0]);
```

Also, read books like Javascript Patterns to learn how to write clean, understandable, maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you Veteran Coder. I just purchased that book. I appreciate everyone's help, I'm a designer who got in over his head with this particular project. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the commenters who helped and accept this answer.  If you'd prefer to give the answer to one of them, have them put an official answer and accept it.  We all like to get good reputation.

Comment: I just tried to implement the code above into my actual page and it's not working. Am I implementing it incorrectly?

http://www.ortorderdesk.com/product/prepare-for-your-closing-copy/

Comment: It looks like location.js is loading and running before your DOM is loaded.  You need to be aware of load order and run your script when everything is in the browser, not before.

Comment: OK... I just put it right before the closing <body> and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe use in conjuction with `window.onload`?

Comment: try that - it is the right way to do it.  In jQuery, you'd do it in `$("document").ready()`.  Also, go back to your original jsfiddle and do it there to prove to yourself it works at all.  I did it, and it worked for me.  Use the browser's development tools to watch the load and execution order of your page. I just looked at your source, and your field names don't match the references in the code, e.g., `input_1_21` instead of `input_21`

Comment: Hmm... thanks! The classes are `input_1_21` but I think the names are `input_21`.

Comment: Alright, I see that those are the ID values, and the names match.I ran it through the debugger for you.  There are two elements that have the class 'cart', and the first one is not the form.  It is an LI.  So, change the [0] to [1].

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense. Thank you for doing the research. I will implement this revision tonight and let you know!

Comment: No go on the [1].... still doesn't work. I need to get a handle on when it loads. That must be the issue.

Comment: Use the debugger. I can tell you the object is defined when you assign the event.

Comment: What am I looking for?

Comment: WHen I change the dropdown is says "Can not read value of undefined.

Comment: When I load it with the Firefox Debugger on, lists the scripts in the one side panel, and this script (location.js) is listed before www.ortorderdesk and product/prepare-for-your-closing-copy/. Does that mean it is loading before the DOM is loaded still?

Comment: If love to hear the root cause.

Comment: There was yet another, more mysterious, `<li class="cart">` that was generated dynamically apparently. With help, came up with a way to reference that particular item regardless of how many similarly named items loaded on the page.